# SQL Query conditional on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with historical option prices, and I would like to select for each day the contract(s) that have the closest expiration date. Below is a min examples:

```
Date         ExpDate   Unique Contract ID
1/1/2022     2/1/2022   1
1/1/2022     3/1/2022   2
2/1/2022     3/1/2022   3
2/1/2022     4/1/2022   4
```

For this table I would like to obtain this:

```
Date         ExpDate   Unique Contract ID
1/1/2022     2/1/2022   1
2/1/2022     3/1/2022   3
```

Not sure if this could be done with maybe a `group by`? The query below isn't working as it won't allow me to select all the columns for some reason:

```
SELECT *, MIN(ExpDate)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Duplicate of many of the [groupwise-maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groupwise-maximum) questions.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server, I have updated the tag.

Comment: Is `date` always earlier than `ExpDate`?

Comment: Yes, correct. Date is always earlier than ExpDate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Get the latest records per Group By SQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/35219261/90527)," "[How to find the record in a table that contains the maximum value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/376518/90527)"

Comment: Yep, I think this is what I was looking for. The answers below seem to be using a similar approach. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, and other RDBMS that support analytic functions, you can use:

```sql
SELECT "DATE", ExpDate, ID
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "DATE" ORDER BY ExpDate - "DATE") AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
) t
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

For SQL Server, the equivalent would be:

```sql
SELECT "DATE", ExpDate, ID
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "DATE" ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd, Date, ExpDate))
           AS rnk
  FROM   table_name t
) t
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("DATE", ExpDate, ID) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', DATE '2022-01-03', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', DATE '2022-01-03', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', DATE '2022-01-04', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE | EXPDATE | ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 3 |
> | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 |

*[Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fd854317ce03fb130592fd37a348fa32)* *[SQL Server db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=d756185645c5e6b0e5f50e5c7cf9e1bd)*